# vectorize lookup in matlab 2-d matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

Hi I am having trouble at vectorizing the following Matlab code segment

```
for i=1:n;
    vec(i) = mat(index(i),i);
end;
```

where **index** is an permutation of 1:n.

Code is very slow in this form. I have checked some notes on vectorization tricks in Matlab to no avail but I might be missing something obvious. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` and `1:n` to get the relevant parts of `mat`.

```
vec = mat(index, 1:n);
```

If `n` is actually the number of columns in `mat`, you can simply do:

```
vec = mat(index,:);
```

Comment: I did not see the second solution at first. `n` is indeed the number of columns in `mat` and I indeed missed the obvious! the first solution seem to work faster.  thanks

Comment: @user2635254 That's interesting because the second solution should be significantly faster. Also please consider marking it as the solution if it works for you.